# What is the latest version of firmware for the AirPods (first generation)?

Tags: software-update, firmware, airpods

My AirPods still show a firmware version of 3.7.2 after many months.

Is that the version 3.7.2 current in January 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 6.8.8

Apple released version 6.8.8 in 2019-09 for the AirPods ( 1st generation).

---

Wikipedia reports the latest firmware as:

> 1st & 2nd gen: 2C54 (December, 2019)

…but I believe that is incorrect. As far as I know, 2C54 was released only for the 2nd generation, not the 1st generation.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, 3.7.2 is the current version.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8414325